# Is there a way to use linux line commands using vuejs?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, system-calls, child-process

I know that Nodejs can be used as back-end and front-end with Vue, but I don't know if it works either because what I want is that if in a vue component I press for example a button called execute, this makes the call to the function inside methods and execute the command with child_process library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.JS works in frontend, so you need something as backend. I had developed some same  task. After pushing a button,there was an API call to rest backend and backend on expressJS executes system call.

When you start vue in dev mode (npm run serve), it uses it`s web backend for development only, in production mode you may compile it (npm run build) to static files.

Easy solution is to use vue + expressJS.  In express app you cat code some rest methods and call what you need in server environment. Also you can set static place in expressJS app (it`s means static content place), and put production vue files in it.

Secondary you can use nuxt.js because it has it`s own web server in dev and product mode. But in this case you will also need implement an expressjs app to nuxt web backend

Comment: Now I understand it very well, thanks for the information it has been of great help :)